# How to write a lexer rule for UUID v4 in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to write a lexer rule for UUID v4 in ANTLR4?

```
UUIDV4: [0-9a-fA-F]{8}'-'[0-9a-fA-F]{4}'-'[0-9a-fA-F]{4}'-'[0-9a-fA-F]{4}'-'[0-9a-fA-F]{12};;
```

I am also importing another grammar where I have the following rule

```
WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```

I don't want to allow any spaces before and after dashes in UUID V4 while satisfying the `WS` rule. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR does not have a `{...}` quantifier. You will have to repeat them yourself. Something like this should do it:

```
UUIDV4
 : HEX_4 HEX_4 '-' HEX_4 '-' HEX_4 '-' HEX_4 '-' HEX_4 HEX_4 HEX_4
 ;

fragment HEX_4
 : HEX HEX HEX HEX
 ;

fragment HEX
 : [0-9a-fA-F]
 ;
```